# Creating a tikzpicture using nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could anyone help me create a tikzpicture using nodes The picture I want and the code I have so far are shown below. There are two things I'm struggling with: First, how to make two arrows coming out of the last rectangle? Second, how to add that switch element between the circle and the first rectangle?
[image]

```
% Tikz block diagram for the product processor
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}



% Definition of styles for blocks and multiplier
\tikzstyle{block} =  [rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=2em,align=center,
minimum height=2em, node distance=8em]
\tikzstyle{mult}=[draw=black, thick, circle, node distance = 2cm] % multiplier


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, >=latex]
  \node [align=center,color=black] at (-2,-1) (snlabel) {$c$};
  \node[circle, draw,node distance=5em, right of=snlabel, color=black] (circlelabel1){$\times$}; 
  \node[block, right of=circlelabel1, color=black, node distance=5em] (sumlabel)  {text1}; 
  \node[block, right of=sumlabel, color=black, node distance=7em] (detlabel)  {$d=e$\\$f=g$}; 
  
 
  \draw[->, color=black] (snlabel) -- node [above] {}(circlelabel1); 
  \draw[->, color=black] (circlelabel1) -- node [above] {} (sumlabel); 
  \draw[->, color=black] (sumlabel) -- node [above] {\color{black} $b$} (detlabel); 




  % add whitespace to bottom and top
  \node at (4.5,-3.5) {\hspace*{1em}};  
  \node at (4.5,-.4) {\hspace*{1em}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Your question as currently formulated falls into the "do-it-for-me" category of questions which is not well received on this website. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) showing what you have tried so far and which abstract concept you are struggling with. A good starting point is either the [TikZ documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or searching for examples on this very website through the search bar.

Comment: Thanks, KersouMan. I couldn't figure out how to get the two arrows coming out of the second rectangle. Also, I couldn't figure out how to add a switch element between the circle and the first rectangle. I have posted the code I have so far.

Comment: Using the calc tikzlibrary you can define points like `($(detlabel.north east) !0.25! (detlabel.south east)$)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend the `positioning` library and the usage `right=of A` not `right of=A`. Also, note the use of `tikzset` for defining styles; `\tikzstyle` should no longer be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw, text width=4em, align=center, minimum height=2em},
    mult/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=6mm, path picture={\draw(path picture bounding box.south east)--(path picture bounding box.north west)
        (path picture bounding box.south west)--(path picture bounding box.north east);}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm, thick]
\coordinate(A) at (0,0);
\node[mult, right=of A](B){};
\coordinate[right=of B](C){};
\node[block, right=of C](D){text1};
\node[below=1cm of D](M){$d$};
\node[block, right=of D](E){$d=e$\\[2ex]$f=g$};
\node[right=1cm of E.25](F){$h_1$};
\node[right=1cm of E.-25](G){$h_2$};
\draw[->] (A)--node[above]{$c$}(B);
\draw (B)--(C);
\draw[->] (M)--(D);
\draw[->] (D)--node[above]{$b$}(E);
\draw[->] (E.25)--(F);
\draw[->] (E.-25)--(G);
\draw[<->] (D)--([xshift=8mm]C)--([shift={(.2,.5)}]C);
\draw[<-] ([xshift=3mm]C) arc(180:90:.5)node[above]{$t=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm new to tikzpicture and I'm quite impressed that you were able to implement that switch so efficiently!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it.

Many things should be different. Let me highlight just a few:

- add a border to standalone, as it will look better, at least during development
- adding white space to the bottom isn't needed
- most packages aren't needed here
- `arrows.meta` provides many nice arrow tips
- style `block` isn't a good choice in my view
- `default color` is black, so you don't have to specify it (and if so, not the way you did)
- you may want to use `inner sep` with the functional blocks
- style `arr` would be very useful, if you'd add a line color, like blue; just do it in the beginning, like so: `arr/.style={->,blue},`
- I used polar coordinates (indicating the intersection with the default shape of the node) to place the outgoing signal lines
- if you `anchor` those nodes as given, they‘ll start in the right place
- read the last `\draw` statement: move to center of sumlabel, new position -1.5 cm in y direction, place a text there, draw a line from there towards sumlabel

[image: result]

```
% Tikz block diagram for the product processor
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} % <<<
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}



% Definition of styles for blocks and multiplier
%\tikzstyle{block} =  [rectangle, draw=black, thick, text width=2em,align=center,
%minimum height=2em, node distance=8em]
\tikzstyle{mult}=[draw=black, thick, circle, node distance = 2cm] % multiplier


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily, 
    >={Latex},
    arr/.style={->},
  ]
  % ~~~ nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \node[align=center,
        %color=black
                ]       at (-2,-1) (snlabel) {$c$};
  \node[circle, 
        draw,
        node distance=5em, 
        right of=snlabel, 
        color=black]       (circlelabel1){$\times$}; 
  \node[%block,
        draw, 
        right of=circlelabel1, 
        %color=black, 
        inner sep=2mm,
        node distance=5em]  (sumlabel)  {text1}; 
  \node[%block, 
        draw,
        right of=sumlabel, 
        %color=black, 
        node distance=7em,
        inner sep=5mm,
        align=center] (detlabel)  {$d = e$ \\\\ $f = g$}; 
  
  % ~~~ connectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw[arr] (snlabel)      -- node [above] {}   (circlelabel1); 
  \draw[arr] (circlelabel1) -- node [above] {}    (sumlabel); 
  \draw[arr] (sumlabel)     -- node [above] {$b$} (detlabel); 
  
  \draw[arr] (detlabel.35)  -- +(1,0) node[anchor=west]{$h_1$};
  \draw[arr] (detlabel.-35) -- +(1,0) node[anchor=west]{$h_2$};
  
  \draw[arr] (sumlabel) ++(0,-1.5) node[anchor=north]{$d$} -- (sumlabel);


%  % add whitespace to bottom and top
%  \node at (4.5,-3.5) {\hspace*{1em}};  
%  \node at (4.5,-.4) {\hspace*{1em}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### P.S.: some clean-up

[image: cleaned-up]

```
% Tikz block diagram for the product processor
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone} % <<<
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    font=\sffamily, 
    >={Latex},
    arr/.style={->},
    blockS/.style={ draw,       
                    inner sep=2mm,
                    node distance=5em},
    blockB/.style={ draw,        
                    inner sep=5mm,
                    node distance=7em,
                    align=center},
    mult/.style={   circle, 
                    draw,
                    node distance=5em},
  ]
  % ~~~ nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \node                      at (-2,-1) (snlabel)       {$c$};
  \node[mult,  right of=snlabel]        (circlelabel1)  {$\times$}; 
  \node[blockS,right of=circlelabel1]   (sumlabel)      {text1}; 
  \node[blockB,right of=sumlabel]       (detlabel)      {$d = e$ \\\\ $f = g$}; 
  
  % ~~~ connectors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw[arr] (snlabel)      -- node [above] {}   (circlelabel1); 
  \draw[arr] (circlelabel1) -- node [above] {}    (sumlabel); 
  \draw[arr] (sumlabel)     -- node [above] {$b$} (detlabel); 
  
  \draw[arr] (detlabel.25)  -- +(1,0) node[anchor=west]{$h_1$};
  \draw[arr] (detlabel.-25) -- +(1,0) node[anchor=west]{$h_2$};
  
  \draw[arr] (sumlabel) ++(0,-1.5) node[anchor=north]{$d$} -- (sumlabel);

 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, MS-SPO. That was extremely helpful.

Comment: @DiSh, kindly have a look at my "P.S.: some clean-up" (BTW: two `[above]` statements are not needed at the moment, unless you had something in mind.)